# undefined offet error in arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting a problem please help me.

this is my array

```
Array
(
    [0] => subject7
    [1] => subject6
    [2] => subject5
    [3] => subject3
    [4] => subject2
)
```

and my array size is 5

```
$sub= array();
        for($j=0; $j<=$size; $j++)
        {
        $sub[] = $subject_value[$subject[$j]];

        }
```

but it is giving me a error message **Undefined offset: 5**

Comment: There is no [5] element in your array

Comment: You'll have to provide more info: What is `$size`, what are the two arrays you're using... basically, the error is saying that you're trying to access `$subject[5]`, but the highest key is 4. Possibly replace `$j<=$size` with `$j<$size` will fix it

Answer (score 3):

The error occured because you dont have a 5th element in the array.So change the code like the following

```
$sub= array();
        for($j=0; $j<$size; $j++)
        {
        $sub[] = $subject_value[$subject[$j]];

        }
```

In this case

```
$j <= $size
```

will iterate the loop 6 times and so it looks for the 6th element which is $size[5] since the key starts from 0 and you dont have a 6th or $size[5] element in the array.So you will get the error.So you need to iterate the loop 5 times as your array size is 5.So you have to change the condition as $j < $size in the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

do

```
for($j=0; $j<$size; $j++)
```

Answer (score 2):

change

```
$j<=$size
```

to

```
$j<$size
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sub= array();
for($j=0; $j<=$size; $j++)
{
    $sub[] = $subject_value[$subject[$j]];
}
```

should be

```
$sub= array();
for($j=0; $j<$size; $j++)
{
    $sub[] = $subject_value[$subject[$j]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `<=` operator and it also check the index number 5 and make the condition true for this index. Even though there is only indexs till 4.

```
for($j=0; $j<$size; $j++)
```

change it to `<` operator according to above code as there is only index 4 from 0 and then it make 5 array element.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid such common mistakes, you could use a foreach loop:

```
foreach($subject as $item){
    //work here
}
```

This way you will never try to access a non-existing element (in your case $subject[5]).